# Toggling HTML visibility using CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visibility

Ok so I have a div that contains a canvas and a span which contains an image. I want it such that if the user hovers over or focuses on the div that the image inside of the span will appear. The image wil be invisible otherwise.

**Long story short I want to have a canvas with a red 'X' on the corner that is only visible when the canvas is active**

```js
$('image-canvas').hover(function() {
  $('delete-image').addClass('active');
}, function() {
  $('delete-image').removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.delete-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.delete-image>img {
  width: 32px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.delete-image.active>img {
  width: 32px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas-container" tabindex="1">
  <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
  <span class="delete-image">
            <img src="file:///E:/Apps/Emoji-App/emojis/icons/if_erase_delete_remove_wipe_out_181387.png"/>
        </span>
</div>
```

The hover event fires just fine but the image refuses to toggle visibility. Any help?

Comment: can you use jsfiddle.net and update the link.

Comment: have you tried display: none / display: block?

Comment: When you use a class, your selector should be $('.delete-image')... (you forgot the point)

Comment: $('image-canvas') should be $('#image-canvas') (referring to the ID of the element) . Anyway check my below answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a class within your selector, write it like this:

```
$('.myDiv')
```

When you use an ID within your selector, write it like this:

```
$('#myDiv')
```

For further informations, check out [jQuery's learning center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/) website.

Comment: This was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have misspelled or have not specified the jQuery selector type (class `.` or id `#`). Please try this:

```
$('#imageCanvas').hover(function () {
  $('.delete-image').addClass('active');
}, function () {
  $('.delete-image').removeClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

See here .

```js
$("#control").mouseover(function(){
  $('#img').show();
});
$("#control").mouseout(function(){
  $('#img').hide();
});
```

```css
#img{
  display:none;
}
#control{
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='control'>Show/Hide</div>

<img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/404.svg' id='img'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not well-phrased, so I ain't sure I totally understood what you wanted.
When you try to select by class, don't forget the dot '.'

```
$('image-canvas').hover(function () {
                $('.delete-image').addClass('active');
            }, function () {
                $('.delete-image').removeClass('active');
            })
```

When using functions 'addClass', 'removeClass', 'toggleClass', etc. - you don't use the '.' sign because it is a function that refers only to classes. On the other hand, when using jQuery selector $(' ') or vanilla querySelector(' '), you should declare what kind of attribute you are selecting by, those will be '#' for ID, '.' for Class, and if you want to select by anything else you can use $('*[anyattribute=anyvalue]'), in your clase it could be $('span[class=delete-image]').
Good luck